# Angular 4: Setting img src base href inside of innerHTML

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml

In my Angular 4 app, I am using innerHTML to show description of the exercises which are in HTML format.

```
<li *ngFor="let exercise of exercises">
  <div [innerHTML]="exercise.longDescription"></div>
</li>
```

These descriptions can also contain images

```
<img src="/file/na\6ad7k4ynon6yh2qcibcdqxwcey.jpg">
```

and that is where I am struggling because I need to set the base href for these images to localhost:8080 where my backend is. Angular is trying to get them from standard localhost:4200 (ng serve) so I am getting [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPduS.png).

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: `Angular is trying to get them from standard localhost:4200` can you elaborate this point? And also what errors?

Comment: Do you have configured your files as assets inside the angular-cli.json? If not, your files will not be copied to the dist folder and will not be available for the web-server

Comment: @AakashThakur localhost:4200 is where your Angular 4 apps are accessible for development (if not specified otherwise by --port).

Comment: Can you show your service call?

Comment: @MarkusKollers I don't want anything saved. I get exercise from server using http.get and in contains shortDescription which is in HTML format. But the src of images inside this HTML description is relative path - to an image which is also stored on the server. I want to set different base for it however.

Comment: @AakashThakur Not sure what service you mean. Maybe my comment to Markus can answer your question?

Comment: So your images are on localhost:8080?

Comment: @MarkusKollers yes.

Comment: Can't you modify your backend to return absolute pathes?

Comment: @MarkusKollers probably but then it would not work for both production and development. For development I want the base localhost:8080 while for production I want server's API there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, not sure if is the cleanest one but it gets the job done.

I created a function in my exercise model that adds environment.URL to the src (which is localhost:8080 for development and server's API for production).

```
public getHTML () {
    return this.longDescription.replace(/<img src="([^"]+)">/, '<img src="'+environment.URL+'$1">');
  }
```

and I access it like this

```
<div [innerHTML]="exercise.getHTML()"></div>
```

instead.

Environment const looks like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  URL: 'http://localhost:8080'
};
```